# ReactJS import/require file/page from another loaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been looking for some examples but no luck or I just don't know how it looks like. What I am trying to do is to do what I would do in Rails or PHP - so Render or Include. I want to store content for different pages in different files. I know I can store it in one file but it wouldn't be recommended to have hundreds lines of code... I want to keep it short in many files. (unless its not how ReactJS should be build)

Here is my page structure:

[image]

How would I link projects.js to app.js - and call it to display content from projects.js

**app.js**

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');

var Projects = require('./pages/projects');

var Header = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
            <div className="navmenu">
              <ul id="menu">
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="projects">Projects</Link></li>
                <li>News</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        );
  }
});

var Logo = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
      <div className="logo col-md-4">
        <div>
          <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var slide_one = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
      images/slides/blank.gif
    );
  }
});


var Slides = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row wrap">
                <div className="col-md-12 gallery"> 
                  <div className="camera_wrap camera_white_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div className="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>Great cars</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div className="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>Fast cars</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div className="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>Super cars</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div className="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>We have it all!</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
});

var Footer = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="line7">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row footer">
            <div className="col-md-12">

                <br /><br />

              <h3>Subscribe for Our Newsletter!</h3>
              <p>Subscribe to our newsletter email to get notification about fresh news, latest promos, giveaways and free stuff from Skew. Stay always up-to-date!</p>
              <div className="fr">
                <div className="boxCenter">
                  <input className="col-md-6 fEmail" name='Email' placeholder='Enter Your Email'/>
                  <a href="#" className="subS">Subscribe!</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="lineBlack">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row downLine">
            <div className="col-md-12 text-right">

            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left copy">
              <p>Copyright; 2016 Cruisin. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 text-right dm">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var Home = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 cBusiness">
                  <p>Home Page</p>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
});

var About = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 cBusiness">
                  <p>About Page</p>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="home">
          <div className="headerLine">
            <div id="menuF" className="default">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">

                  <Logo />

                  <Header />
                  <Slides />

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

                  {this.props.children}

        </div>

        <Footer />

      </div>

    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router >
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('mount-point')) ;
```

**projects.js**

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');

var Projects = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (

            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 cBusiness">

                  <p>Projects Page</p>

                  <br />
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I have made few attempts to call it. I am new in JS and still making mistakes.

How to make it work, or is there another way to do this in ReactJS?

Apologies if there is another topic like this - I don't really know technical name for what I want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that you are exporting `Projects`. Add this to the bottom of the projects.js file `module.exports = Projects;`.  And the in App.js `var Projects = require('./pages/projects.js');`.

Comment: Thanks for answer - sadly your solution isn't working. The link works as it did but content is not displaying.

Comment: Does `Projects` import and just not display, or does it not import at all?

Comment: I don't know how to check it - in dev tools this is what displays http://prntscr.com/a4xq26 - I am guessing there is either something wrong with route...

Comment: One thing in your above code you have `require('./pages/projects');` but it needs to be `../`  to move up one directory level.  If that doesn't fix it, place a `console.log(Projects);` just after you import projects and see what you get in dev tools.

Comment: `../` crashes everything - app.js is in main dir - so it should be `./` - I know subl is confusing with layout. I have look at console and let you know shortly.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're correct about the `../` I misread the file tree.  The console.log is a good thing.  It shows that Projects, is getting imported properly.  If you remove the `<Route path="projects" component={Projects} />` from router, does everything work normally?

Comment: Yes, everything works as it did - the only change is that 'Projects' is not displaying at all as it does not change to blank - it stays on what it was before.

Comment: Not sure that this would effect it, but in Projects.js you only need to include react, not the Router etc.  I would remove those and see if it's possibly causing a conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103879/discussion-between-rickt-and-fresz).